# What are the current open problems in dilation theory?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I just started doing my PhD in mathematics. My topic is unitary dilations of operators. I've been reading a lot of papers on that subject so far (especially about the dilation of $n \ge 3$ commuting contractions and the corresponding von Neumann inequality, and so-called pairs of $q$-commuting contractions), but I still fail to see what the current open problems in dilation theory are.

Could anyone maybe point them out? I know that a general problem is e.g. for a complex polynomial $p$, finding such a value $C_n$ that $$p(T_1, \ldots, T_n) \le C_n \cdot \sup_{z \in \overline{\mathbb{D}^n}} | p(z)|$$ and that there are some partial results. But this is not what I'm asking about as I am familiar with the general problems in dilation theory.

What I'm asking is what are some ***specific*** problems in dilation theory, which yet have to be solved by someone. I ask about specific problems, because I feel as if just knowing the general problems is getting me nowhere and I feel as if I'd need some specific problem to work on.

What I mean by "specific" problem? An open question which has been left to others after a mathematician has worked on a specific case/example in dilation theory (in the realms of the "general problem"). An (already solved) example of a specific problem would be finding out whether an $n$-tuple of $3 \times 3$ matrices satisfies the von Neumann inequality after having it proved for $2 \times 2$ (the answer is yes!). For the curious out there: It does not work for $4 \times 4$ matrices as there exists a counterexample.

I'm looking forward for your answers, it will be a great help for my PhD studies.

Thanks

Comment: You may find the following survey useful https://www.utgjiu.ro/math/sma/v03/a11.html  Standard disclaimer: this is not an investment advice.

Comment: @OnurOktay Thanks for the link. Could you explain how it might be useful for my problem? Basically, my problem is that I don't know which exact problems to tackle in dilation theory, as all I know are the general problems known in dilation theory (and not specific ones which I could at least try to solve in my PhD thesis). I've read a lot of mathematical papers on dilation theory, but I couldn't find any current specific open problems which are yet to solve.

Comment: You’ll have much better luck talking to your advisor, who knows your background and interests.  Helping you figure out which problems to work on is an important part of their job!

Comment: In addition to @OnurOktay's suggestion, another very relevant reference is Orr Shalit's recent survey paper ["Dilation theory: a guided tour"](https://zbmath.org/1494.47012).